# What is the best approach to declare variable in typescript for class assignment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I don't want to declare `accountHandler` as `any` it is not good practice. What is a better approach to create class variable when you have to assign it to class in the constructor.

#### main.ts

```
{
 private accountHandler: any= {};
 private requestLOB: string[] = [];


    constructor() {
        if (process.env.ENABLEBackendSwitch === "true") {
            this.accountHandler = new AccountBalanceHandlerV2();
        } else {
            this.accountHandler = new AccountBalanceHandler();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it just be a union type of `AccountBalanceHandler | AccountBalanceHandlerV2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `any` you can use `AccountBalanceHandlerV2 | AccountBalanceHandler`. But you actually don't even need to set the type as TypeScript will infer the value for you based on what you assign it to in the constructor (so long as you remove your default assignment):

```js
class A {
  private accountHandler;


  constructor() {
    if (process.env.ENABLEBackendSwitch === "true") {
      this.accountHandler = new AccountBalanceHandlerV2();
    } else {
      this.accountHandler = new AccountBalanceHandler();
    }
  }
}
```

`accountHandler` is inferred to be of type `AccountBalanceHandlerV2 | AccountBalanceHandler`.

Comment: yes i tried that first thing but it throws error ` error TS7008: Member 'accountHandler' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: @hussain Maybe you're on an older version of TypeScript. It was added a few versions back. Just set the type explicitly to `AccountBalanceHandlerV2 | AccountBalanceHandler`.  Here's a TypeScript playground showing that the type can be inferred on newer versions:

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCzAPYFcB2AXAQmcrgFMAJMVAExHwCcA1AJmgG8AoaV6AB2QCMQBLYaADNelCOgByYALb4AXNDGVeqAOYBuJgF8moSDHhI0WHCQLEyFSoxZtOPftHBjJM+YuXqtTHU-3XW7EoAbmDo+NBgCCgY5uRUGt6sSKiKyMDoiJQAFACU-my8gtBZgYgEUAB0+KhBFQCi4rCYADJ12MAA1tWkAMoA7rzowAAW0AC8E9AAROiUyPhTecxsbOjDvBAVkYYxJHFWY9Co+H1wUUbYuGZ7lnS5Giua0PggEOHLK9BrG1vnuxZUcZHE5nHbGK5EG5Ue42VjaOFaIA

Answer (score 1):

Typescript will actually infer the type of fields initialized in constructors. So if you don't have any annotation, it will be infered.

```
class X {
    private accountHandler;
//           ^?  X.accountHandler: AccountBalanceHandlerV2 | AccountBalanceHandler
    constructor() {
        if (process.env.ENABLEBackendSwitch === "true") {
            this.accountHandler = new AccountBalanceHandlerV2();
        } else {
            this.accountHandler = new AccountBalanceHandler();
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxgNghgzjAEBBMYD2BXAdgFwEJWkzAFMAJKTAEwmICcA1AJngG94BiAT3gF54BGAL6hIsBMjRY8BCiXJUatVhwAevAYPgjoceAA1WoeMfgAHWgEsAblGzF4UFBhzzqdANygA9F5N+-AHoA-EYmaJgw2LToYNiotAAUAJSGIP4mFgBm8AnmqCRwAHTEmFaFAKIAcoi4ADLl+GAA1iWUAMoA7hbYYAAWvDx8AERR6MRDKSyh6X7YvRYwhY6SLhRuSnyYxB1ITlL4hHJrikzJnmkzmsQQMPZTFzMmcwtLe6sKdOpbOxLO0odkY50M7TfzCB7wcHgoA)

But the best practice is to actually be explicit about the type:

```
class X {
    private accountHandler: AccountBalanceHandlerV2 | AccountBalanceHandler
    constructor() {
        if (process.env.ENABLEBackendSwitch === "true") {
            this.accountHandler = new AccountBalanceHandlerV2();
        } else {
            this.accountHandler = new AccountBalanceHandler();
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxgNghgzjAEBBMYD2BXAdgFwEJWkzAFMAJKTAEwmICcA1AJngG94BiAT3gF54BGAL6hIsBMjRY8BCiXJUatVhwAevAYPgjoceAA1WoeMfgAHWgEsAblGzF4UFBhzzqdAFxInU-ITkU3BmYAHy9JHF9ZMgDFIxM0TBhsWnQwbFRaAAoASkMQEwL4CwAzeEzzVBI4ADpiTCtqgFEAOURcABlG-DAAazrKAGUAdwtsMAALXh4+ACJk9GIZ3JY4wsLscYsYasdw7FdFdUxiIbDnaT9ohTomHIBuVcLNYggYexX8tfXN7d3zg7oRxOZx8MiIV0C90eBWEn2MsNhQA)